# Uniquely identify each of a certain user's devices

Tags: ruby, identity, uniqueidentifier

I have a downloadable Ruby client which users can install on various devices they own. The client just runs every so often and sends various data to a server.

I would like to be able to uniquely identify each of a user's devices so that I can tell which device various request originated from.

- The ideal identifier would exist cross platform so that I can use is on OSX, Windows, Android etc.
- It is not necessary for it to be unique among the set of all computers, just unique among the set of a single user's computers.
- I would rather not write my own identifier to the file system if that can be avoided.
- The identifier should persist. Permanently if possible.

What is the simplest way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thus far, I haven't found a satisfactory way to do this without writing to the users machine.

Currently, I use the [UUID gem](https://github.com/assaf/uuid) to write a 36 char unique identifier to the filesystem and then read it back whenever I have to.

Another option if you are using > Ruby 1.9.2 is to use the [SecureRandom.uuid method](http://rubydoc.info/stdlib/securerandom/1.9.2/SecureRandom#uuid-class_method) which does the same thing. This method is not available in Ruby 1.8.7 however.

Answer (score 1):

With the [sysinfo](http://sysinfo.rubyforge.org/) gem, using `sysinfo.to_s` for example you get strings like `ruby-unix-osx-i386`.

But that would not work if a user has two machines with the same architecture. Also I'm not sure if sysinfo supports platform like Android for example.